# TypeError When Passing Arguments to a Python Thread

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am trying to write a simple threading program. It works well when I don't try to pass any variables the target function.

```
import threading
import time
import datetime

def my_function():
    thread_start_time = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    thread_start_time_remove_microseconds = thread_start_time[:19]

    print("\n\nThread Execution Start Time: ", thread_start_time_remove_microseconds)
    print("I am being printed by mythread. Sleeping for 5 seconds. Main thread will wait till I finish")
    time.sleep(5)

    thread_end_time = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    thread_end_time_remove_microseconds = thread_end_time[:19]

    print("Thread Execution End Time: ", thread_end_time_remove_microseconds)


def main():
    mythread= threading.Thread(target=my_function, name="thread1")
    mythread.start()

    print("\n\n","=" * 31,"I am printed by the main thread","=" * 31,"\n\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which results into:

```
Thread Execution Start Time: 

 2018-09-09 17:02:46
 =============================== I am printed by the main thread =============================== 


I am being printed by mythread. Sleeping for 5 seconds. Main thread will wait till I finish
Thread Execution End Time:  2018-09-09 17:02:51

Process finished with exit code 0
```

However, when I try to pass a variable to the function, I get below error:
    import threading
    import time
    import datetime

```
def my_function(one_variable):
    print(one_variable)
    thread_start_time = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    thread_start_time_remove_microseconds = thread_start_time[:19]

    print("\n\nThread Execution Start Time: ", thread_start_time_remove_microseconds)
    print("I am being printed by mythread. Sleeping for 5 seconds. Main thread will wait till I finish")
    time.sleep(5)

    thread_end_time = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    thread_end_time_remove_microseconds = thread_end_time[:19]

    print("Thread Execution End Time: ", thread_end_time_remove_microseconds)


def main():
    mythread= threading.Thread(target=my_function, name="thread1", args=("This is one variable from main"))
    mythread.start()

    print("\n\n","=" * 31,"I am printed by the main thread","=" * 31,"\n\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It results into:

```
=============================== I am printed by the main thread =============================== 


Exception in thread thread1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dparvez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\dparvez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: my_function() takes 1 positional argument but 30 were given


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Can someone please help as why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a comma to make `args` a tuple, like this:

```
mythread= threading.Thread(
    target=my_function
    name="thread1",
    args=("This is one variable from main",))
```

This is because threading.Thread() expects args to be some **iterable** and enumerates it to get all args to pass to your function.

The expression ("string") is equal to just "string" - and it IS an iterable, resulting in ("s", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g"). Not what you wanted. To tell Python that ("string") is a one-element tuple and not a parenthesized expression, do ("string",).